# how to connect a solar panel to a charge regulator via a relay

Tags: arduino, panel

In the first montage I was connecting a solar panel of a range Vco=24,8V to a charge regulator of 12V, I was connecting a valve of 12V as a charge.

I wanted to command the opening and closing state of the solar panel in the circuit via a relay of 12V(QIANJI JQC-3F(T73)-12VDC.

I wanted to apply the same thing for the valve when related in the circuit via a second relay which have similar caracteristics as the first relay. [below is the first part of the montage i have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4uT8.jpg)

The problem is that I have declared in arduino as inputs A0 and A1 two push buttons and as an output to pin 12 the output to the montage in the image. I have used the following code:

```
int panel = 12;
int boutonON = A0;
int boutonOFF = A1;
void setup() {
    pinMode(panel, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(boutonON, INPUT);
    pinMode(boutonOFF, INPUT);
}
void loop() {
    if (!digitalRead(boutonON))
        digitalWrite(panel, HIGH);
    if (!digitalRead(boutonOFF))
        digitalWrite(panel, LOW);
    delay(100);
}
```

When I excecute the code above, normally when i push the first button(A0) the panel should be connected to the charging regulator and providing a voltage in its inputs because the relay will change the contact because it is maitained by a 12 V battery, and vise versa when I push the second button (A1) the button the panel should not be alimenting the charge regulator because the circuit will be open. But that's not what happened in my case, when I make the montage and when i connect the + of the relay to the + of the battery nothing happenes but when I connect the - of the battery to the - of the relay is connected the panel works and charges the charge regulator, I wanted to switch the state using both push buttons but nothing happenes until I disconnect the - of the battery from the - of the relay.

I wanted normally to change the state of the panel via the relay using both push button but it did'nt work and i don't khnow why. Can any one help me I don't khnow what to do to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

A few points here-

By 'montage', I think you mean 'program'?

The pins you are using (A0, A1) are analog pins, not digital ones.  Try using pins 3 and 4, for example.

Also, you may have issues with the inputs, as they aren't set up to use pullup resistors; check out the documentation on INPUT_PULLUP; https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial .  This could be the reason you are getting odd results.  Try using the serial port to see the status of your inputs.

This is just me (a generally mono-lingual person), and I can get the gist of your post, but some of it isn't that clear.  If English isn't your first language, and you are using Google translate, you might want to find a forum that is in your native language, *or*, post your question with the translation *and* in your first language (who knows, maybe someone brilliant here knows it!).  Is 'montage' the correct translation for 'program'?  I know in the UK I've seen 'programme'...

Answer (score 0):

By montage I wanted to montage of the circuit I have done, thank you for your answer I'm going to try it.

can you please see the link below if you have an idea: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981595/create-a-visual-studio-interface-to-control-a-solar-pv-system?noredirect=1#comment55719315_33981595
Thank's